# How to fill the joint between tiles and cabinets in a kitchen backsplash?

Tags: tiling, backsplash

We have a tiled kitchen backsplash, see photo below.

[image]

In between the tiles, there's grout.

I wonder what choice of materials I can use (if it's different from the
grout I use between the tiles) in the joints between the tiles and cabinets
(marked red in the photo).  Please suggest materials and discuss their pros and cons.

I want a white material to match the grout color of white.  Also, whatever material I use should be moisture and heat-resistant due to the backsplash area.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would use white caulk for this, hand-squeezed from the small tubes available at the hardware store. It's flexible enough that it won't crack as the wood cabinets move against the tile, and dries rubbery and impervious to water. Smooth it into the crack with your finger and it'll be nearly invisible. Takes about thirty seconds.

Over time, you'll need to wipe it clean of cooking grease, and it will eventually crack and peel, at which time you can dig it out and reapply it quite easily.

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry for a very basic question: how is white caulk different from white silicon?  What are pros and cons in this particular case?  I believe you apply white silicon quite similarly.

Comment: There are many types of caulk, silicone rubber is the base material for silicone caulk. It adheres well and is very resistant to moisture, heat, and grease when cured.

Comment: Most silicone caulk is not "soap and water" clean up, you will need mineral spirits (paint thinner) to clean hands, tools, etc. Latex caulk is water based so is easier to use but generally not as durable.

Comment: I was originally thinking white latex caulk (hence the wet finger). White silicone caulk would definitely last longer, but you will want to slick it with something else--or carefully wipe your finger off afterward.